# ¿Cómo detectar Tablet Android en Java?

Tags: java, android

¿Hay alguna forma de detectar que la app este corriendo en `Tablet`o en `Smartphone`?

Hasta ahora lo hago detectando el ancho de `pixeles`, pero me encuentro la gama Samsung Galaxy S3, S4... que tienen más resolución que una tablet y no es optimo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olvidate de detectar el ancho de pixeles o la densidad, este método es el que uso y es el sugerido por google:

```
public static boolean esTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

---

Adicional info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout

```
public void deterScreenSize() {

    if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {   

        Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
               Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {   

        Toast.makeText(this, "Normal sized screen" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
               Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {    

        Toast.makeText(this, "Small sized screen" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
               Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {     

        Toast.makeText(this, "XLarge sized screen" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "El tamaño de la pantalla no es ni X grande, ni grande, ni normal o pequeña" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```