# Como poner títulos dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla en android

Tags: java, android

Hola lo que necesito es hacer que me salga un titulo dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla, los títulos los tengo en `strings.xml`.

Así lo puse pero no me funciona, si me pueden ayudar lo agradezco.

```
    else if (id == R.id.layout_id) {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout ==  Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
                    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.titulo_tablet));
                } else {
                    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.titulo));
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo un método para detectar si es Tablet o no tu dispositivo:

[¿Cómo detectar Tablet Android en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7924/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-tablet-android-en-java)

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context ctx){
        return (ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE; 
}
```

usando este método (el cual recibe el contexto), podrás definir correctamente que valor de strings.xml usar de acuerdo a el tipo de dispositivo:

```
if (isTablet(getApplicationContext())) { //Tablet.
    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.titulo_tablet));
} else { //Teléfono.
    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.titulo));
}
```

Comment: Ok voy a intentarlo, gracias.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que son enlaces de un main drawer y cuando se presionan me llevan al fragmento con su respectivo titulo ya están en un public Boolean y son varios, cuando el titulo es largo no cabe en una pantalla normal

Comment: @Jeiner puede usar un texto adecuado dependiendo del tipo de dispositivo o también cambiar alguna propiedad como el TextSize, pero regularmente lo que se realiza es que se muestra el texto pero se define la propiedad android:ellipsize="end"  para cortar el texto o implementas un marquee para que el texto se mueva y sea visible al usuario.

Comment: Gracias, creo que lo dejare así, debe ser en java:              android:ellipsize="end" esto no me serviria